# How do I change an inputs border colour without changing the style?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something pretty simply; change the border colour of an input. In both IE11 and latest stable Chrome, changing the color also changes how it looks (appears 3D/thicker):

[image: Wonkey CSS Borders]

If I try "1px solid red" then the border looks the same, but the size changes!

1. Why does changing the colour seem to do more than just change the colour
2. How can I just change the colour without changing anything else (style, thickness, spacing, size, etc.)

I've tried messing with border-width and other properties, but none of them result in the exact same size/spacing as the default with only the colour changed :(

**(Please try your changes in JSFiddle before posting... so many people are posting bad answers and then deleting them! http://jsfiddle.net/S2TxT/4/)**

```
<input type="text" value="Default" />
<input type="text" style="border: 1px solid red" />
```

Comment: You should've mentioned chrome at first place, all the answers are getting downvoted for no reason :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien I did; I mentioned both IE11 and Chrome. It's probably not only these browsers, they're just what I'm using and noticed it in.

Comment: Actually you edited after 2-3 minutes, when already users had answered..

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Danny - just a thought on all this. I don't think you'll ever get inputs to look the same across browsers *"without changing anything else (style, thickness, spacing, size, etc.)"*. Browsers and input's all do something different and do exhibit some "odd" (in the world of logic and reason) behaviours when changing properties. The real answer is to find the specs for each browser - if you really want to know! Anyway, have offered an answer below.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 Nothing in my question relates to things looking the same across browsers. I simply wanted to understand why IE11 (or Chrome) seem to change thins *other* than the colour, when I set border-color. Why would padding change? I'm not after consistency, I just wanted to change the border colour with nothing else within any given browser :(

Comment: @Mr.Alien Did you click on the edit and look at the change? The IE11 and Chrome text has remained unchanged since the original post. The edit was to add a JSFiddle comment at the bottom. Apology accepted.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny sorry, of course I mean Chrome and IE - was just making the point about that certain changes will. I've also just realised why. See here - http://jsfiddle.net/S2TxT/12/ !!

Comment: @DannyTuppeny and this, to prove the point. http://jsfiddle.net/S2TxT/14/ The default input type=text doesn't have a solid border, even though it looks like one.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/S2TxT/19/ They're rendered differently, but have same values?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Yes. Wow. As I said, give up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IE11 and Chrome, this got me matching boxes.

As for *why*... browsers will be browsers?

```
<input type="text" value="Default" />
<input type="text" value="Default" style="padding: 2px 1px; border: 1px solid red" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S2TxT/11/

**EDIT**

After further investigation, it becomes apparent *why* this might happen:
http://jsfiddle.net/S2TxT/18/

Comment: This is the best answer I can see - avoids hard-coding height which the previous best did (which was deleted due to downvotes!). I did have to just set "2px" instead of "2px 1px" for padding, but that might be due to some defaults from Bootstrap or similar.

Comment: Excellent :) Glad it satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way I can find of fixing the problem. Unfortunately, it involves changing the height CSS. Crazy, I know, just for a border color change!

```
<input type="text" value="Default" />
<input type="text" style="border: 1px #cecece solid; padding: 2px; height: 16px;" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S2TxT/10/

Comment: Yep; this works well - though looks like the height becomes unnecessary once you add the padding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below CSS:

```
input{
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
input:last-child{
    border-color: red;
}
```

Note that different browsers apply different default styles to elements which can go against your expectations.

You may want to look at using something like [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) so you can more easily anticipate the results applying your CSS across all browsers.

[You can also look at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) applying `appearance:none;` to your `input` elements to override browser specific styling directly.

Have a look [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PJ5SV/1/) for a more comprehensive fiddle.

Comment: This doesn't work either; the box gets wider, but not taller to match the default

Comment: @Danny Tuppeny: Then try removing the padding from top and bottom. And this feature will differ from browser to browser.

Comment: You may want to add `input{-webkit-appearance: none;}` to your css

Comment: @Ankur140290 I appreciate it will vary; I'm not after consistency across browsers; just trying to understand why it's so difficult to change the border in colour *in either IE11 or Chrome* without messing everything else up! :/

Comment: @DannyTuppeny, you'll need to normalize the initial state of the input to override the browser defaults- see http://jsfiddle.net/PJ5SV/1/

Comment: @Danny Tuppeny: All this happens because of the default properties set in the browser. As every browser has its own set of pre written css, we always face this kind of problems. Just add reset css file as the top of all the css files in yr code. and you can then code easily.

Comment: @Ankur140290 Changing the border-color should not magically also change padding or height. I'm not asking for a consistent solution across browsers, I was asking for *a* solution in *either* browser that changed the border colour and nothing else. Apparently this isn't simple; which is what I feared, but hoped I'd overlooked something :(

Answer (score 0):

add class to the input :
html :

```
<input class="border" />
```

css:

```
.border { border: 1px solid #ddd; /*you can write your hex code for color replacing #ddd*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend inspecting the CSS being applied to those input elements using FireBug lite.

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Most browsers set their own CSS as default for input boxes and it's annoyingly convoluted to say the least. Goole chrome for instance, sets an inset border and then overrides it some places in different ways depending on the side of the input box.

If you look in the Inspect Element Computed CSS box for the input element, you will see what is applied and see how to overide it.

Comment: The built-in tools in both IE11 and Chrome fail to show this base CSS; are you sure Firebug will be any better? Don't want to spend time installing unwanted junk on my machine and find it's the same :/

Comment: (I'm also really surprised that it's so difficult to change a border colour!)

Comment: Firebug is vaslty superior to anything in any browser. The only reason you have to use FireBug lite is because it's IE. Both Firefox and Chrome have full versions. Just search FireBug and you should be fine.

Comment: Even with this, I'm not sure it explains why the padding changes when I change border-color :(

Answer (score -2):

you can use border-width and height attribute(border-width:thin)

```
<input id="tdfre" style="border-color:red;border-width:thin;height:18px;padding:1px;" type="text"/><input type="text">
```